# how to increase size of selected icon in bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 30),
        unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 24),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              index == 0
                  ? "assets/homeScreenImages/appointment_active.png"
                  : "assets/homeScreenImages/appointment_unactive.png",
              height: 25,
              width: 25,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            label: APPOINTMENT,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              index == 1
                  ? "assets/homeScreenImages/home_active.png"
                  : "assets/homeScreenImages/home_unactive.png",
              height: 25,
              width: 25,
            ),
            label: HOME,
          ),

          // BottomNavigationBarItem(
          //   icon: Image.asset(
          //     index==2
          //         ? "assets/homeScreenImages/d_l_active.png"
          //         : "assets/homeScreenImages/d_l_unactive.png",
          //     height: 25,
          //     width: 25,
          //     fit: BoxFit.cover,
          //   ),
          //   label: DOCTOR_LOGIN,
          // ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              index == 2
                  ? "assets/homeScreenImages/more_active.png"
                  : "assets/homeScreenImages/more_unactive.png",
              height: 25,
              width: 25,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            label: MORE,
          ),
        ],
        selectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 8,
        ),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 7,
        ),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        // selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 50),
        // unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 24),
        onTap: (i) {
          setState(() {
            index = i;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: index,
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code is same as like image

```
height : index == 0 ? 30 : 25,
width : index == 0 ? 30 : 25,
```

same as other tabs 1, 2 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 different widget for menu items like below :

```
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home_linear.svg'),
                label: '',
                activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/home_fill.svg')),
```

Set height  and width for each item help you to change it, even with 2 different image.